# Proof of convergence of a telescoping series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

> Show that the telescoping series below converges if and only if the
>   $\lim_{j\to\infty} c_j$ is defined and finite.
>
> $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} c_j - c_{j+1}$$

Not really sure where to start for this, proofs are nowhere near my strong suit. Would $c_j$ not be a constant? Why would I take the limit of a constant?

Gotta go to class now, will check back this afternoon. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: my progress (from a reply below) that anyone can comment on:

I'm currently trying to look at this and still not seeing it. Here is what I've played with. As you work through the sum (Starting at 1, I typo'd in the original question) you have: $(c_1-c_2)+(c_2-c_3)+(c_3-c_4)+...(c_{n-1}-c_n)+(c_n-c_{n+1})$.

For every term other than the first and last it gets subtracted and then added, essentially giving a sum of $c_1-c_{n+1}$. the last term is going to be either substantially bigger or substantially smaller than c1, but I'm still missing something huge if I'm even on the right track. Am I even on the right track?

**Edit2**: Here is my rough answer as it currently stands, is it missing anything?

A rough "proof-ish" description the answer as I think I have it now: Because of the telescoping nature of the series, every term after the first and except for the last is cancelled out by the one after it. This leaves us with a partial sum of Sn=c1-cn+1. Because c1 is finite, in order for the sum to converge lim(cn+1) cannot be infinite and must be defined.

Comment: Go to the FAQ section, there you'll find directions for using LaTeX in this site.

Comment: I just suggested an edit for $\LaTeX$.  I recommend you look at it if/when it is accepted and see if you can dissect.

Comment: Re: your newest edit: You basically have the answer (congrats!), except that your sum should be $c_1-c_{n+1}$.  After that, the rest of the proof should be easy. :)

Comment: I just tried to edit this to reflect that and saw your suggested edit. I see that I am kind of there, but I guess I'm lacking on the theory why. Sn=c1-c_{n+1} and the sum is equal to c1-lim(1->inf.)c_{n+1} but how does this equal a "proof?"

Comment: A rough "proof-ish" description the answer as I think I have it now:

Because of the telescoping nature of the series, every term after the first and except for the last is cancelled out by the one after it. This leaves us with a partial sum of Sn=c1-cn+1. Because c1 is finite, in order for the sum to converge lim(cn+1) cannot be infinite and must be defined.

Is this missing anything?

Comment: You're almost there. You've correctly noticed that the partial sum $S_n=c_1-c_{n+1}$. Now, since you were asked to establish an "if and only if" statement, you have two tasks. First, prove that if the limit of $c_j$ is defined and finite then the series converges. Second, if the series converges then the limit of $c_j$ is defined and finite. Appealing to the definitions of limit and convergent series will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $j$, $c_j$ is a constant, but if we let $j$ change, then $c_j$ is not a fixed constant (for example, we may consider $c_j=1/j$). Now, my hint will be to approach the problem the following way: $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_j-c_{j+1}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{j=0}^N c_j-c_{j+1}.$$Now the sum on the right-hand side is finite, so what happens if we write out a few terms? I'd suggest trying it when $N=2$ or $N=3$ and deduce what happens for all larger $N$.

Comment: I'm currently trying to look at this and still not seeing it. Here is what I've played with.

As you work through the sum (Starting at 1, I typo'd in the original question) you have (c1-c2)+(c2-c3)+(c3-c4)+...(c_(n-1)-cn)+(cn-c_(n+1)). For every term other than the first and last it gets subtracted and then added, essentially giving a sum of c1+c_(n+1). the last term is going to be either substantially bigger or substantially smaller than c1, but I'm still missing something huge if I'm even on the right track.

Am I even on the right track?

Comment: It won't let me edit again, I'm down to Sn=c1-c_(n+1) and the sum is equal to c1-lim(1->inf)c_(n+1) but not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I think you're on the right track: $S_n=c_1-c_{n+1}$. Now $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(c_1-c_{n+1})=c_1-\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n.$$ Thus the only way the sum can converge is if the limit of the sequence exists and is finite.